# recursion and rendering in Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

The following code works as expected when the variable 'works' is set to true (in chromium) but doesn't when it's not.  I'm trying to figure out why.  Although I can just use the working one, probably I should understand better why the non-working one doesn't work.  Why should there be any difference between pushing array items one at a time with this.push and setting the entire array with this.set?

```js
'use strict'

var data = [{
  id: 1,
  children: [{
    id: 2
  }, {
    id: 3,
    children: [{
      id: 4
    }, {
      id: 5,
      children: [{
        id: 6
      }, {
        id: 7
      }]
    }, {
      id: 8
    }]
  }, {
    id: 9,
    children: [{
      id: 10,
      children: [{
        id: 11
      }, {
        id: 12
      }, {
        id: 13
      }]
    }, {
      id: 14
    }, {
      id: 15
    }]
  }]
}];

class Polymerology2Element extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() {
    return 'polymerology2-element';
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      nodeData: {
        type: Array,
        value: [],
        notify: true
      },
      node: {
        type: null,
        value: null,
        notify: true
      }
    };
  }

  isOdd(num) {
    return num % 2;
  }


  addNodes() {

    var works = true;

    if (works) {
      if (this.node !== null) {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; this.node !== undefined &&
          this.node !== null && this.node.children !== undefined && i < this.node.children.length; i++) {

          arr.push(this.node.children[i]);
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.set('nodeData', arr)
        }, 0);
      }
    } else {
      if (this.node !== null) {
        for (var i = 0; this.node !== undefined &&
          this.node !== null && this.node.children !== undefined && i < this.node.children.length; i++) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.push('nodeData', this.node.children[i])
          }, 0);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    if (Polymerology2Element.instance === undefined) {
      this.nodeData = data;
      this.node = null;
      Polymerology2Element.instance = 0;
    } else
      Polymerology2Element.instance += 1;
    this.instance = Polymerology2Element.instance;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.addNodes();
  }
}

window.customElements.define(Polymerology2Element.is, Polymerology2Element);
```

```css
:host {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+polymer+v2.3.1/components/" />
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html" />

<polymerology2-element></polymerology2-element>

<dom-module id="polymerology2-element">
  <template>
    <ul>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[nodeData]]" as="item">
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isOdd(item.id)}}">
          <li>Instance: {{instance}}, Node: {{item.id}} (odd)</li>
          <polymerology2-element node="[[item]]"></polymerology2-element>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{!isOdd(item.id)}}">
          <li>Instance: {{instance}}, Node: {{item.id}} (even)</li>
          <polymerology2-element node="[[item]]"></polymerology2-element>
        </template>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Maybe the DOM and/or rendering can't keep up when you add one at a time? I've had chokes before. Before Polymer, yes, but on operations much slower.

Comment: Thanks, but then is there a way to wait for the rendering to catch up before pushing the next one?

Comment: And anyway it never seems to catch up because nothing is ever rendered.

Comment: Watch this 35 minute lesson on the browser event loop and updating by Jake Archibald: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0    I'm thinking you entered a blocking situation.  As I said, years ago I tried to update the DOM while fetching one record at a time from a server RDMS. The DOM locked up, so I went back to grabbing a block of records before updating.

Comment: That's a great video, thanks Thad.  I probably will have to refer back to it a number of times before I really get it though.  Then maybe I'll be able to see why it blocks.  Also thanks Andrew Bone for the edit.